# Watersheds and Catchment delineation in Earth Engine only with included datasets

Tags: python, javascript, google-earth-engine, watershed, catchment-area

Is there a possibility to derive Watershed boundaries or catchment areas by using one or more of the integrated data sets in google earth engine?

The available data sets are:

1. [WWF HydroSHEDS Hydrologically Conditioned DEM, 3 Arc-Seconds](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WWF_HydroSHEDS_03CONDEM)
2. [WWF HydroSHEDS Drainage Direction, 3 Arc-Seconds](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WWF_HydroSHEDS_03DIR)
3. [WWF HydroSHEDS Void-Filled DEM, 3 Arc-Seconds](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WWF_HydroSHEDS_03VFDEM)
4. [WWF HydroSHEDS Flow Accumulation, 15 Arc-Seconds](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WWF_HydroSHEDS_15ACC)

I know i can export them as raster and work with QGIS or ARCMap to derive the boundaries but anybody knows how to derive it with python or java script inside the google earth engine without exporting the data?

Comment: I think this post on the forum could help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-earth-engine-developers/4UON8SFoKD4  and a link https://code.earthengine.google.com/e9f6c746c186935cfbc52befc398b81b . It is made by Gennadii Donchyts